# Flutter released app is not supporting http ( not https ) request in android version 10

Tags: android, flutter, rest, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Flutter app does not load content that needs to be fetched by API call. My server is `http://{ serverIP }/`. While live debuging it loads the content on all devices without any issue. but after release, it only works on the device which has an android version. I tried this `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`  but did not solve that issue.

Comment: yes.
path:
`Project\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml`
Added this in xml.

Comment: it is also there

Comment: yes. I dont have any other option. is there any solution for this **http**.My senior gave me this IP to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`to AndroidManifest.xml

[image: androidmanifest.xml]

then follow this step:

1. stop your app
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. run your app again

it solves my problem a few days ago.

Comment: does it work in **release** or **Build APK** using this *flutter build apk --split-per-abi* ?

Comment: it works on release but I haven't tried it using `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

Comment: yes it is working for  `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`  as well. Thanks